# Does $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(\ln n)^2}$ converge or diverge by comparison test?

Tags: calculus

$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(\ln n)^2}$$
I was trying to use $\frac{1}{n}\leq\frac{1}{\ln(n)}$ which concludes that $\frac{1}{\ln(n)}$ diverges.

But after this I know I can't power both sides of the inequality.

Any help?

Comment: what is $x$...?

Comment: Multiply both sides of the inequality by $ln(n)$.

Comment: Or, if $n=e^t$ use $e^t>t^2$.

Comment: In the long run, $\ln n<n^c$ for any $c>0$. Including $c=\frac12$

Comment: Since $\log(n)\le \sqrt{n}$, then $\frac1{\log^2(n)}\ge \frac1n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to apply the comparison test is to compare:
$$
\frac1 {(\ln n)^2}\ge\frac1 {n\ln n},\text { for } n\ge 2.
$$
The latter series diverges by integral test.

---

Alternatively one can show repeatedly applying l'Hopital rule that
$$
\forall p>0:\quad \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(\ln n)^p}{n}=0,
$$
which means that there exists such $N_p$ that for all $n>N_p $: $(\ln n)^p<n $.

Comment: Since $\log(n)\le \sqrt{n}$, then $\frac1{\log^2(n)}\ge \frac1n$.

Comment: Yes for $p <e $, the inequality $(\log x)^p <x $ holds for all $x>0$. But since  for the convergence only the behavior at large $n $ matters I have not mentioned this case separately.

Comment: It is not true that $\log^p(x)<x$ for all $x>1$ (and certainly not for all $x>0$) and for all $p>1$.  It is true that for all $p>1$, $\log^p(x)<x$ for Sufficiently Large $x$.  But it is true that $\log(x)<\sqrt x$ for all $x>0$.

Comment: Yes we completely agree on this!